# C# aspnet-core Swashbuckle No operations defined in spec

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Setup swagger using a custom base path but none of the controllers are showing up in the documentation, the swagger.json file is mostly empty paths:{}, it isn't auto discovering.  Shouldn't this be automatic or what is misconfigured to stop the controller endpoints from appearing in swagger generated documentation?

Startup's ConfigureServices

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "My Service",
        Description = "My description",
    });
});
```

Startup's Configure

```cs
app.UseSwagger(config =>
{
    config.RouteTemplate = "api/{documentName}/swagger.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/api/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = "api/swagger";
});
```

Example controller not showing up

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")] //tried api/[controller] and [controller] neither worked
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

the UI loads on the correct URL with the error in the HTML: "No Operations defined in spec!" and when clicking the JSON link it gives back a file created with empty paths: {} so the UI loads as expected and is accessible on the path expected but it doesn't populate the UI or JSON file with any of my controllers

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:port/api/swagger/index.html?. If the UI opens, you can click on the swagger.json link under the title

Comment: Yes, the UI loads with the error: "No Operations defined in spec!" and when clicking the JSON link it gives back a file created with empty paths: {} so the UI loads as expected and is accessible on the path expected but it doesn't populate the UI or JSON file with any of my controllers